# 400 bad request error for Prometheus query

Tags: curl, prometheus, grafana

Everybody, I am trying to pull a report from Prometheus using API. But, it throws 400 bad request. I have tried the same query in Prometheus, It is showing the proper data.
Could anyone please let me know how to fix this.

Basically, I need to average  http_request_in_latency_seconds_sum and http_request_in_latency_seconds_count.

```
root@project:/# curl 'http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query_range?query=avg(http_request_in_latency_seconds_sum / http_request_in_latency_seconds_count)&start=2021-05-01T00:00:00Z&end=2021-05-02T00:00:00Z&step=30s'
400 Bad Request
```

Comment: Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly escape special characters  `/`  (two whitespaces and the slash in this case) in the query parameter:

```
?query=avg(http_request_in_latency_seconds_sum%20%2F%20http_request_in_latency_seconds_count)
```

You can also make `curl` escape characters for you with `--data-urlencode`:

```
curl 'http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query_range' \
    --data-urlencode "query=avg(http_request_in_latency_seconds_sum / http_request_in_latency_seconds_count)" \
    --data-urlencode "start=2021-05-01T00:00:00Z" \
    --data-urlencode "end=2021-05-02T00:00:00Z" \
    --data-urlencode "step=30s"
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! 
I have two whitespaces and then the slash. but still I am getting 400 error. Could you please let me know if there is any other alternative way to fix it. The -data-urlencode is showing success for the request.

Comment: @Vivek Show me the query with escaped characters that gives the error.

Comment: I have tried like this root@project:/# curl 'http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query_range?query=avg(http_request_in_latency_seconds_sum  /  http_request_in_latency_seconds_count)&start=2021-05-01T00:00:00Z&end=2021-05-02T00:00:00Z&step=30s'
400 Bad Request

Comment: I suspect the query might be broken. as you can see the 1st half is highlighted and rest is not.

Comment: @Vivek `curl 'http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query_range?query=avg(http_request_in_latency_seconds_sum%20%2F%20http_request_in_latency_seconds_count)&start=2021-05-01T00:00:00Z&end=2021-05-02T00:00:00Z&step=30s'`

Comment: I have tried as shown above. but it is showing status as error.   root@project:/# curl 'http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query_range?query=avg(http_request_in_latency_seconds_sum%20%2F%20http_request_in_latency_seconds_count)&start=2021-05-01T00:00:00Z&end=2021-05-02T00:00:00Z&step=30s'
{"status":"error","errorType":"execution","error":"query processing would load too many samples into memory in query execution"}

Comment: @Vivek Well, it's not `400 Bad Request`, it's too broad query. Try tuning `start`, `end` and `step` parameters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231977/discussion-between-vivek-and-anemyte).